# project.json versioning format

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for a formal definition of version number formats for .NET Core project.json files.

**version**
Visual studio creates a default version number of "1.0.0-*".  I would love for this to mean the * gets updated on successive builds (it doesn't).  The build version number is 1.0.0.  What does the * mean and what are the legal possibilities?

**dependencies**
I expected the dependency numbering to follow the nuget [versioning rules](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning) given that KPM is basically a nuget front-end, but it doesn't appear to support bracket numbering (eg "[1,2)") - I get "not a valid version string" when I try anything other than a blank or x.x-* format.

Outside of the source, does anyone have a link to a formal definition?

Comment: See this https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/442 and also the comments in related pull request.

Comment: We do this with our build, and should probably bake it into KPM. Our build scripts set the environment variable K_BUILD_VERSION to a timestamp. That automagically increments the version everytime we build a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with looking into the source for a definition. I think that's the most accurate place to search, especially now that vNext is hosted on GitHub.

Looking at the exception described, we're pointed to SemanticVersion.cs.

[In the method `TryParseInternal`, it's fairly obvious why you're running into issues when attempting to declare min/max versions that way.](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/069dfb964a86ab505dd6df5e5495434072346b6c/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/NuGet/SemanticVersion.cs#L174) There is simply no handling for `[,]` or `(,)` built into that method.

If we look into the regular NuGet version specification, [it's obvious that `TryParseVersionSpec` does have this handling built in.](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/386dd351b69902e7870a083cf2732706dbde12b7/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/NuGet/Utility/VersionUtility.cs#L343)

As for documentation specifying acceptable formats, you'll probably have to wait until it's out of CTP status. If you believe it's an issue, you should [document it in GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues). The contributors are very responsive to these types of issues. Personally I'm not sure if there's a need for setting a maximum version of a dependency when it's deployed with your build.

Comment: I guess I feel that code defines how things are currently implemented, not necessarily how they should work or how they were meant to be used.  Besides which, the level of difficultly required to use code as documentation is quite high.  Imagine using .net compiler source for documentation instead of MSDN

Comment: @MattFrost: My point is that you probably won't find updated documentation at this point given that the specification is being developed/refined as it's coded. I would be extremely weary of any documentation you find at this point.